# Trim trailing zeros in Fortran print/write

Tags: io, fortran

How can I print without trailing zeros? For example if there was a function `nice`:

```
real*8 ff
ff = -3.5d0
print*, "there are ", nice(ff), " horses"
```

or a formatter `t`

```
print'(a,t,a)', "there are ", ff, " horses"
```

should give:

```
there are -3.5 horses
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works by limiting the precision (there may be some round off errors after ca 16 decimals) and then checking from the end where the last non-0 character is

```
function nice(ff) result(out)
    character(:), allocatable :: out
    character(20) :: str
    real*8, intent(in) :: ff
    integer ii
    write(str,'(f20.8)') ff
    str = trim(adjustl(str))
    do ii = len_trim(str),1,-1
        if (str(ii:ii)/="0") exit
    enddo
    out = str(1:ii)
end
```

Note that interval indexing like `(ii:ii)` is required for strings.

Comment: This solution works if the argument has a nice representation in binary (as `-3.5` does).  But if one changes `-3.5` to `-3.4` it produces `-3.39999999999`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Very good point. Yes I'd like a better solution. But I assumed writing to limited precision would solve that. It seems like you have more than 8 digits in the decimals?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Also, if putting `ff=-3.4`, it gives me `-3.4000001`, but with `ff=-3.4d0` it works correctly.

Comment: Well, I just let my digit rest on the `9` key until there was a long line of them printed, I didn't actually count how many.  But you, and anyone else who bothers to read this, get the point - ensuring that a number has what the (naive) user thinks is the right number of trailing `0`s is actually quite tricky.

Comment: I basically aim for the equivalence of `numpy.set_printoptions(precision=8, suppress=True)` in python. That `8` could be a parameter of course. So that at a given precision, you ignore any trailing zeros.

Comment: But I think the problem you encountered with `-3.4` seem to be because of casting single to double precision. I edited the question ti be `-3.5d0` which is what it should be given its `real*8`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative and easier approach which will work (so long as the total length is smaller than the character array 'CDUMMY') is shown below:

```
        PROGRAM MAIN
        IMPLICIT NONE
        REAL*8 FF
        FF = 3.5

! ***** WRITE FF TO A CHARACTER ARRAY. ONCE IN THIS FORM YOU CAN REMOVE TRAILING SPACES
        CHARACTER CDUMMY*12
        WRITE(CDUMMY,'(F12.1)') FF
        WRITE(*,'(3A)')  'There are ',TRIM(ADJUSTL(CDUMMY)),' horses'

        END
```

If you are not too concerned about spaces (as opposed to trailing zeros), then you could simply write using the format specifier Fx.y. For example, to write a floating point number to one decimal place,set y to 1. x is the total size of the number to be outputted including decimal place. So F6.1 would be okay so long as there are less than '9999.9' horses (I feel sorry for the 10,000th horse). In context, it would like so:

```
WRITE(*,'(A,F6.1,A)') 'There are ',FF,' horses'
```

Which would yield the following (the underscores represent spaces):

> There are ___3.5 horses

Comment: And if there are 0.01 horses?

Comment: And why use `F12.1` with `trim(adjustl(cdummy))` instead of `F0.1` with `ff` directly?  Which even has the advantage of not printing a large number as`************`?

Comment: Assumption on my part; I assumed the number to be outputted would only ever have 1 number after the decimal point.